# Microsoft Graph API User AD Sync

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

For a user in azure, created by AD Sync the mobilePhone number is not shown. For a user created by using the interface the mobilePhone number is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this document to check [Attributes synchronized to Azure Active Directory using Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized). As stated in the document for Exchange online user phone number attribute is synchronized to AAD.